# How to read data from mongodb using python?

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7

Here is the json:

```
"work": {
    "secondary_sku": [],
    "internal_work": [ 
        {
            "name": "NCB",
            "LOB": "RUNME",
            "rm": "prabhu",
            "skills": [ 
                "python", 
                "javascript libraries", 
                "java applets", 
                "py", 
                "sqoop"
            ],
            "role": ObjectId("589c6da731beda27110af128"),
            "description": "Strong understanding of JavaScript, its quirks, and workarounds\n\nBasic understanding of web markup, including HTML5- and CSS3\n\nGood understanding of advanced JavaScript libraries and frameworks such as: AngularJS, KnockoutJS, Backbone.js, ReactJS, DurandalJS, Vue.js etc.\n\nGood understanding of asynchronous request handling- and partial page updates\n\nKnowledge of advanced JavaScript Concepts like Closures,- Promises- and Callbacks",
            "responsibility": "Strong understanding of JavaScript, its quirks, and workarounds\n\nBasic understanding of web markup, including HTML5- and CSS3\n\nGood understanding of advanced JavaScript libraries and frameworks su- ch as: AngularJS, KnockoutJS, Backbone.js, ReactJS, DurandalJS, Vue.js etc.\n\nGood understanding of asynchronous request handling- and partial page updates\n\nKnowledge of advanced JavaScript Concepts like Closures,- Promises- and Callbacks",
            "current": false,
            "start": ISODate("2017-03-30T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "end": ISODate("2017-03-31T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "billable": false,
            "client": "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to read "work" details data from mongodb.
I tried like this:

```
work = [nref.get('internal_work', '') for nref in details.get('work', [{}])]
```

and

```
work = details["work"].get("internal_work","")
```

Note: `details` is the name of the loop variable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your question well because the Json you sample has an incorrect format. Provides more information about what is the unique ID, name of the collection and database.
Anyway, if you use Pyhon I recommend using the [PyMongo](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/) driver.

Using PyMongo, the search code would look something like this...

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
 
def main ():
     
     # Connection to the MongoDB Server
     mongoClient = MongoClient ('Your_IP: Your_Port')
     # Connection to the database
     db = mongoClient.Your_DataBase
     #Collection
     collection = db.Your_Colection
     
     details = collection.find ({"Work": "id_"})
             
if __name__ == "__main__":
         main ()
```

The query (find) will depend on the correct structure of your Json.

For more information about how to use Pymongo use this [link](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html).
regards,

Answer (score 1):

Read data from mongodb using pymongo

```
    import pymongo
    import json
    client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
    collection_USER = client[simple]
    Define_Collection_for_USER_FILE = collection_USER['USER']
    dict_for_user = {}
    for obj in Define_Collection_for_USER_FILE.find({}, {'_id': False}):
        dict_for_user.update(obj)

    d = dict_for_user
```

Comment: I like this better because the format of the calls looks correct, but there could be more explanation as to what the code does, e.g. `'simple'` and `'USER'` seem to be assumptions about the database structure

Answer (score 0):

Answering this in 2023, so I'm using Python3 to read the record with the above structure shown in `work` from a collection `details` of such records in an `employees` database:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

database_host_uri = "localhost:27017"   # or wherever the db host is
client = MongoClient(database_host_uri)
employees = client["employees"]
employee_details = employees.get_collection("details")

# assuming the "internal_work" list has only one element as above
for employee_record in employee_details.find():
    employee_work_info = employee_record["internal_work"][0]
    print(f"For {employee_work_info['name']} we have {employee_work_info['skills']}.")
```

If you still need an answer in Python 2.7, note that PyMongo 3.12.0 has [deprecated support for 2.7](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html), so please make sure that the version you're using is not more recent than that.